# Invalid Memory Access with 64 bit dll's on windows 10 only with java11

Tags: java, jna

I have a java application that uses jna to call a 64 bit third party DLL to communicate with scanners (with native 64 bit drivers).  I am receiving an invalid memory access error with the combination of windows 10 / java11 / jna that I do not receive with any other combination.

This code works fine on all the following without errors:

- Windows 7 / 64 bit java 8 runtime
- Windows 7 / 64 bit java 11 runtime
- Windows 10 / 64 bit java 8 runtime

I am using latest and greatest jna (5.3.1) and have tried older versions as well, with the same result.

```
/* Open Scanner */
EZT.TWAIN_SetHideUI(true);
if (EZT.TWAIN_GetSourceList()) {
    if (!EZT.TWAIN_OpenDefaultSource()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot open scanner");
    }
 }

 /* Retrieve scanner capabilities for resolution */
 int hcon = EZT.TWAIN_Get(EZLibrary.ICAP_XRESOLUTION);
 if (hcon != 0) {
     int resolutions[] = new int[EZT.CONTAINER_ItemCount(hcon)];
     ...
 }
 .....
 private interface EZLibrary extends Library {
     int ICAP_XRESOLUTION = 4376;

     void TWAIN_SetHideUI(boolean bHide);
     boolean TWAIN_GetSourceList();
     boolean TWAIN_OpenDefaultSource();
     int TWAIN_Get(int uCap);
     int CONTAINER_ItemCount(int hcon);
 }
```

The call to "EZT.CONTAINER_ItemCount(hcon)" in this example returns an Invalid Memory Access Error.  However, when this code is a part of my larger application and not this sample application, the same code sequence throws the Invalid Memory access error up higher on "EZT.TWAIN_OpenDefaultSource()".

So, in summary:

- windows 7 / java 8 : as expected results
- windows 7 / java 11: as expected results
- windows 10 / java 8: as expected results
- windows 10 / java 11:

  java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
      at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeInt(Native Method)
      at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:426)
      at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:361)
      at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:265)
      at com.sun.jna.Native$3.invoke(Native.java:1202)
      at $Proxy0.CONTAINER_ItemCount(Unknown Source)

My question becomes is there an issue with JNA with win 10 / java 11 or is it something in the third party code, or something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I did end up finding a solution for this.

I am not entirely sure why, but for 64 bit my JNA implementation needed:

```
Long TWAIN_Get(int uCap);
Long TWAIN_Acquire(int hwndApp);
```

With 32 bit it needed to be:

```
Integer TWAIN_Get(int uCap);
Integer TWAIN_Acquire(int hwndApp);
```

So to handle both I just use:

```
Number hcon = EZT.TWAIN_Get(EZTwainPro.ICAP_XRESOLUTION);
```

Doing this resolved the invalid memory access.  I know it is because of the int returned was an unsigned int, but I am not entirely sure why the "long" implementation only works on 64 bit and not 32 bit runtimes.  It has to be different in order to have both work.  Also, the "long" implementation was only needed for win10, not win7, but it works for win7 too.